# how to hide a component if all sub-components are hidden ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

For example consider the code:

```
<div *ngIf="-------NOTEMPTY-------">
  Parent
  <div *ngFor = 'let child of offsprings'>
    <div name="c1" *ngIf="conditions[child.name]">
      Child0
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want Parent division's `ngIf` to be `false` if all its child divisions' `ngIf` are `false`.

**Note : It is not possible to me to collect all the child conditions in the ts file.**

Comment: `offsprings.every(c => !c.condition)`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in the Parent *ngIf condition

```
!offsprings.every(child => !conditions[child.name]);
```

Comment: Edited the answer to search the condition in the conditions map

Answer (score 0):

Used a function call as **`*ngIf = checkIfExists()`** on parent.

```
<div *ngIf="checkIfExists()">
  Parent with children existing
  <div *ngFor = 'let child of offsprings'>
    <div name="c1" *ngIf="conditions[child.name]">
      Child0 {{conditions[child.name]}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Function For Parent ngIf:** 
Appraoch is to traverse every element of `offsprings` array, 
and check if `conditions[child.name]` exists.

```
checkIfExists() {
  let ifDefined: boolean;
    this.offsprings.forEach(e=> {
      if (this.conditions[e.name]) {
        ifDefined = true;
      } 
    });
    return ifDefined;
}
```

**[StackBlitz Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-hide-according-to-child-ngif?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**